# GraphQL sorting case insensitive

Tags: database, api, sorting, search, graphql

How do I sort in GraphQL using case insensitive?
Currently I get all entries with uppercase before lowercase.
Is there a way to ignore titalcase?
My query looks like this:

```
{
  allToolsJson(sort: {order: ASC, fields: [name]}) {
    edges {
      node {
        name
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: The question is not specific to GraphQL but rather to database queries. If you paste the body of the `resolve` function on the `allToolsJson` field (or wherever you query the database), we might be able to help.

Comment: So you mean, sorting is not part of the GraphQL spec? Do I have to add this on my application layer to add this filter to my query?

Comment: Correct. https://github.com/graphql/graphql-js/issues/640#issuecomment-268386839